# Calling web service from SQL Server stored procedure gives execute access denied (IIS Error)

Tags: sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, iis-6

I have created a stored procedure which calls a web service using **Ole Automation Procedures.**

When I call it from one database server it does allow me to call web service, but when I call it from another database server it does not allow me to call web service and throws this response.

I can't figure out where the problem is :

> The page cannot be displayed
>
> **You have attempted to execute a CGI, ISAPI, or other executable program from a directory that does not allow programs to be executed.**
>
> Please try the following:
>
> Contact the Web site administrator if you believe this directory should allow execute access.
>
> HTTP Error 403.1 - **Forbidden: Execute access is denied.**
>   Internet Information Services (IIS)
>
> Technical Information (for support personnel)
>
> Go to [Microsoft Product Support Services](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=8180) and perform a title search for the words **HTTP** and **403**.
>
> Open IIS Help, which is accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr), and search for topics titled Configuring ISAPI Extensions, Configuring CGI Applications, Securing Your Site with Web Site Permissions and About Custom Error Messages
>
> In the IIS Software Development Kit (SDK) or at the [MSDN Online Library](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=8181), search for topics titled **Developing ISAPI Extensions**, **ISAPI and CGI**, and **Debugging ISAPI Extensions and Filters**

Any help is appreciated..

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the webservice called from the two database server is the same on the same machine?

Comment: yes it was both same on two servers..

Comment: Strange.... the error 403.1 indicate that cannot execute server code, the problem seem on webserver. Can you test the webservice call with a windows application?

Comment: infact if i call another web service from that stored procedure, then also it throws same error..i m running IIS 6..

Comment: @bdn02 if i call web service from iis then it is executed correctly but when trying to call from sql its not working...

Comment: Check iis configuration: open iis aqdministrative tool, right-click on website or virtual directory that host the webservices and check the "execute permission": set it to "script only". An image: http://www.symantec.com/business/support/library/BUSINESS/ATLAS/images_v1/281427/scripts.jpg

Comment: i hv tried setting those permissions but unfortunately no luck...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47380/discussion-between-vishal-sharma-and-bdn02)